# How to place items to activate Hover effect under navbar by using CSS only

Tags: html, css

All I want to obtain is; Hover on Toggleicon and nav items will display. Can you help me how to achieve this

```
<header>
  <navbar>
   <DIV class="toggleicon">ToggleIcon</DIV>
     <ul class="items" style="display:none;">
         <li>ITEM1
         <li>ITEM1
         <li>ITEM1
     </ul>
  </navbar>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.items{
  display: none;
}
.toggleicon:hover ~ .items{
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <navbar>
   <div class="toggleicon">ToggleIcon</div>
     <ul class="items">
       <li>ITEM1</li>
       <li>ITEM1</li>
       <li>ITEM1</li>
     </ul>
  </navbar>
</header>
```

Answer (score 2):

```css
.toggleicon:hover ~ .items {
  display: block !important;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <navbar>
   <DIV class="toggleicon">ToggleIcon</DIV>
     <ul class="items" style="display:none;">
         <li>ITEM1</li>
         <li>ITEM2</li>
         <li>ITEM3</li>
     </ul>
  </navbar>
</header>
```

You shouldn't be using the inline style, that's why you need !important in this case. But if you add a custom style for `.items` of `display: none` and remove the inline one, you won't need the `!important`.

Answer (score 0):

```
.toggleicon:hover ~ ul {
    display: block !important;
}
```

use display: none for class .items

Answer (score 0):

```css
.toggleicon:hover .items {
  display:block;
}
```

Comment: This will gives effect for ul that child. His example ul stands next to DIV

Comment: Code only answers are considered low quality. Without sufficient explaination, your answer is hard to understand.
If the OP can't understand your answer, then he also won't be able to reproduce your possible solution. As such it 
would be worthless to him/her. Please add a sufficient explaination of your possible solution.